# Redundant edit message

Tags: discussion, editing

So, I was thinking about editing a post when I thought about, *really thought about,* the message for the editor:

> "We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial edits unless absolutely necessary."

What I think needs to be fixed is

> Avoid trivial edits unless absolutely necessary.

Is it just me, or does the "No trivial unless completely needed" seem confusing? If it's completely needed, then why is it trivial? Perhaps it should be changed to "Avoid trivial edits" or "Avoid trivial edits unless they are, e.g., lots of spelling errors." Or something like that.

Opinions?

Answer (score 8):

**An edit can be trivial but still important or worthwhile.** For example, correcting a misspelling that leads to misunderstandings can be important, yet by some measures trivial. (An edit can also be massive, as opposed to trivial, and utterly unimportant. The extreme case of this would be someone intentionally vandalizing posts.)

That said, that text is network-wide; it's unlikely that we'll be able to change it just on Worldbuilding SE. There's certainly no ready-made interface accessible to site moderators to do it.